# I get "Error" in the translated text field of my application AdroidTranslate .

Tags: android, textview, translation

I'm a beginner into Android application, I tried to run this application 
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html
which translates the text input in the TextView in English to French using google-api-translate-java.  When I click translate I get "Error" in the translated text field.
please help me, thank you !

Comment: Can you post the exact error message from the logcat?

Comment: Yes, exact error message is necessary.